# derivative of a function including a vector

Tags: integration, matrices

given a **column vector** including function of a parameters  $x=\bigg(f(\beta_1),\ldots,f(\beta_m)\bigg)^T$ where $T$ denotes transpose of the vector. Can somebody tells me what is the derivative with respect to $\beta$?
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \beta}=\text{ ?}$$

for example if $f(\beta_i)=\beta_i, i=1,\ldots,m$ then 
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\partial I\beta}{\partial \beta}=I\, 1$$
where $1$ is a column vector of 1

sorry for the silly question. I just confused myself.

Comment: $\beta$ is a vector and $\beta=(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m)$, right?

Comment: yes it is, $\beta=(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m)$

Comment: You seem to have two $f$s, one which maps from vectors to matrices, and another which maps from vector components to vector components. I don't think you should use the same variable for two different functions.

Comment: You notation is inconsistent, so it is difficult to guess what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks you, sorry I am more confused can you explain that more?

Comment: assume $f(x)=x$ then I can write the function as $I\beta$ and derivative is $I \,1$.

Comment: They are saying that you called $f$ a function which acts on a vector, and then you again used $f$ as a function that acts on the vector's components; it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer,

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \beta}= \left( \begin{matrix}
  \frac{\partial f(\beta_1)}{\partial \beta_1} & \frac{\partial f(\beta_2)}{\partial \beta_1}  & \ldots  & \frac{\partial f(\beta_m)}{\partial \beta_1} \\ 
  \frac{\partial f(\beta_1)}{\partial \beta_2} & \frac{\partial f(\beta_2)}{\partial \beta_2}  & \ldots  & \frac{\partial f(\beta_m)}{\partial \beta_2} \\ 
 \vdots & \ldots &  \vdots & \vdots\\
       \frac{\partial f(\beta_1)}{\partial \beta_m} & \frac{\partial f(\beta_2)}{\partial \beta_m}  & \ldots  & \frac{\partial f(\beta_m)}{\partial \beta_m} \\ 
\end{matrix}\right) $$

The important point is that derivative of a vector with respect to a vector is a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{d\beta^\top} = \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial x}{\partial \beta_i} e_i^\top$$
or
$$\frac{dx^\top}{d\beta} = \sum_{i=1}^m e_i\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \beta_i}\right)^\top$$

Then
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \beta_i} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x(\beta+he_i)-x(\beta)}{h}$$